# Calculate date and time differences in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to use Excel 2013 to put together a workbook for timesheet tracking.  As an example, time worked yesterday needs to be entered by 10:00 AM on the next business day.  Weekends become complicated (because the next business day is Monday), but otherwise the layout is as follows:

```
Cell    Cell contents   Cell description

A3      3/11/2014       (Date someone worked)
B3      3/12/2014       (Date when the time was entered into timesheet)
C3      19:00           (Time that the entry was made)
```

In the above example, the time worked on 03/11/14 should be entered into the timesheet by 03/12/14 (the next business day) at 10:00 AM.  In cell D3, I need Excel to calculate the time difference between the next date “after” cell A3 at 10:00 AM (always 10:00 AM) and the date/time of cell B3/C3 (which is when the timesheet was actually updated).  Everything that I’ve tried so far hasn’t worked.  Is this doable?

Thanks

Comment: Dirty little secret:  Dates and times in Excel are expressed in days.  Ie, 12 hours has a numeric value of 0.5, a 2-day time interval is 2.0, and the date is the number of days since some "epoch" (probably Jan 1, 1970).  Whether it's displayed as date, time, or a number depends on what the cell format is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D3 use the formula:

```
=((B3+C3)-(A3+"10:00"))*24
```

As long as A3 and B3 are recognized by Excel as dates, you should get a result of 33 (hours).

Comment: `(A3+(10/24))` instead of `(A3+"10:00")` also could use +if(weekday(B3;2)<weekday(A3;2);48;0) to manage a (1) week-end between both date.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you both @kaarel and @NeronLeVelu for your feedback.  I've combined the info you provided and the attempts I had made prior to posting my question and ended up with:

```
=((Workday(A3,1)+"10:00")-(B3+C3))*24*60
```

A little conditional formatting and I can easily show what was entered and when (early / late) in minutes.